# How does Cosmos Hub facilitate IBC?

Tags: dao-hub, cosmos

I understand the difference between the Cosmos Ecosystem and Cosmos Hub.

However, reading around Cosmos Hub I come across phrases like "Cosmos Hub enables all subsidiary blockchains to communicate".

I thought any chain on Cosmos communicates with any other chain by supporting IBC protocol. Do they all actually route all comms via the singular chain, Cosmos Hub??